# Angular D3: How to change the svg viewport size

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg, angular-reactive-forms

This is not about resposiveness. Its about reactive charts.

I implemented the `ngOnChanges` method to update the chart as the datasource changes:

```javascript
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.data) {
    this.createChart(changes.data.currentValue);
  }
}
```

It works like  charm, except... the chart `heigth` should be dynamic, I mean, grows or shrink depending on `changes.data.length` (more data, more rows to be renderized). I do not constraint the svg element size in the container element.

This is how I built the `<svg>` root element:

```javascript
const viewBoxHeight = data.length * 24 + 40;
const viewBoxWidth = 800;
if (this.svg) {
  this.svg.select('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + viewBoxWidth + ' ' + viewBoxHeight);
} else {
  this.svg = d3.select(this.hostElement)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + viewBoxWidth + ' ' + viewBoxHeight);
}
```

If the `this.svg` object doesn't exist it is created, otherwise, the height **should be** changed.

The problems is it is not working, the height doesn't change. I changed manually the property `viewBox` in the html code via Chrome Developer Tools, and it changes the height (works).

Am I missing something?

PS.: I googled about this and only came about responsiveness issues

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for your issue, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into it I eventually found the problem:

```javascript
    const.viewBoxHeight = data.length * 24 + 40;
    const viewBoxWidth = 800;
    if (this.svg) {
      d3.select(this.hostElement)
        .select('svg')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + viewBoxWidth + ' ' + this.viewBoxHeight);
    } else {
      this.svg = d3.select(this.hostElement)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', '100%')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + viewBoxWidth + ' ' + this.viewBoxHeight)

    }
```

It should select `this.hostElement` instead of `'svg'` as I initially did.